# Sending request headers / authorization axios.post in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, http-headers, axios, jwt

I am having difficulty passing my authorization on my application.
My jwt token

```
export const update_profile = ({
  about,
  birthday,
  birth_location,
  residence_location,
  occupation,
  company_name,
  gender,
  marital_status,
  phone
}) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(
      {
        type: UPDATE_PROFILE
      }
    )
    const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('@token_jwt')
    let url = "/update_profile"
    Axios.post(`${SERVER}${url}`, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      "user": {
        "about": about,
        "birthday": birthday,
        "birth_location": birth_location,
        "residence_location": residence_location,
        "occupation": occupation,
        "company_name": company_name,
        "gender": gender,
        "marital_status": marital_status,
        "cellphone": phone
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        updateProfileSuccess(dispatch, response)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        updateProfileError(err, dispatch)
      })
  }
}
```

This is my code, and I always have the unauthorized return, my token is saved in AsyncStorage when the user logs in.

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser), the headers needs to be provided as a 3rd argument (not 2nd).

**Like this**

```js
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
}

const data = {
"user": {
        "about": about,
        "birthday": birthday,
        "birth_location": birth_location,
        "residence_location": residence_location,
        "occupation": occupation,
        "company_name": company_name,
        "gender": gender,
        "marital_status": marital_status,
        "cellphone": phone
      }
}

axios.post(`${SERVER}${url}`, data, {
    headers: headers
  })
  .then((response) => {
    ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    ...
  })
```

Alternativly, you can pass a single argument which should be an object

```js
...
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  data: data,
  url: `${SERVER}${url}`,
};
axios(options);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it is not working. In my api header is not passing so i am getting error